# Cleveref in conflict with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib, cleveref

I am using the KOMAscript class and the `cleveref` package to create cross-references. Now I would like to cite a theorem where as an optional title I passed the reference with `\citet` from the `natbib` package.

In `final` mode I have no problem, but in `draft` mode this happens. I leave the following MWEs.

Con il pacchetto `hyperref` compila in maniera errata nella modalità `draft`

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


% ------------------------------------------
% PACKAGES FOR REFERENCES and BIBLIOGRAPHY
% ------------------------------------------
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[authoryear, square]{natbib} 
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref} 


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Newton, Isacc},
  year = {1678},
  title = {Something wonderful},
  publisher = {Goofy},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[\citet{key}]
\label{thm:mytheo}
    A wonderful theorem bla bla bla 
\end{theorem}

Here I referer to~\Cref{thm:mytheo}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

However if you remove the `hyperref` package it compiles without problems also in `draft` mode.

What is the problem with the `hyperref` package in `draft` mode and is there any way to solve it?

This is the output with `hyperref`
[image]
This is the output without `hyperref`
[image]
These are the errors
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it would really help if instead of jokes you had written which problem you actually have. BTW: don't use the pdfencoding option it is obsolete.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Try to compile the MWE maybe something interesting happens.

Comment: I did compile and nothing interesting happened, at least nothing that I found unexpected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have revised the question. I hope the problem is now clear.

Comment: try the fix from here https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/238

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works thanks a lot

Comment: You should load `hyperref` and `cleveref` *before* issuing `\theoremstyle` and `\newtheorem` directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounter *no problems* if I execute the `\theoremstyle` and `\newtheorem` directives *after* loading `hyperref` and `cleveref`. By the way, doing so is expressly recommended in section 8.3.1 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package.

[image]

Observe that "Teorema 5.3.1" is *not* rendered in blue in this screenshot, even though `hyperref` is loaded with the options `colorlinks` and `allcolors=blue` and the `cleveref` package is loaded with the option `nameinlink`. Of course, this absence of color happens because the document class option `draft` is set; this option tells `hyperref` not to create actual hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass[draft,italian]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- nice touch!
\usepackage{babel} 

\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{key, author = {Newton, Isaac}, year = {1678}, title = {Something wonderful},
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref} 

% Execute the next 2 instructions AFTER loading hyperref and cleveref:
\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{theorem}[\citet{key}] \label{thm:mytheo}
    A wonderful theorem \dots
\end{theorem}

Here I cross-reference \cref{thm:mytheo}.

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What a wonderful explanation, thank you very much :)